# If $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ exists but $\lim_{x \to a} g(x)$ does not exist, then $\lim_{x \to a} [f(x) + g(x)]$ does not exist

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I am having a bit of trouble with this question and I would like some assistance with this. Here is the question and my attempt.

> Given a function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, it satisfies the following: (1) For every $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, if $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} g(x)$ does not exist, then $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} [f(x) + g(x)]$ does not exist. (2) $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ exists. Show that (1) and (2) are equivalent.

I am expected to show this problem using the $\epsilon-\delta$ proof, but I am unsure if it is correct or if I am on the right track or not. Here is my attempt.

For (2), since the limit exists, then we will denote it by $L$. Then the definition of the limit states that $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0$ such that $\forall x$, if $0 < |x - a| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$.

Now we show (1)

***Proof by Contradiction:*** From (1), it is to be assumed that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ exists. Assume that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} g(x)$ does not exist, but $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} [f(x) + g(x)]$ exists.

Note that the function $g(x)$ can be written as $g(x) = [f(x) + g(x)] - f(x)$, and it follows that by taking the limit on both sides,
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x \to a} g(x) = \lim_{x \to a} [f(x) + g(x)] - \lim_{x \to a} f(x)
\end{equation*}
implying that the limit of $g$ exists, thus a contradiction.

So with (1), it is a little confusing to be of how I should show using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition, and to show that (1) and (2) are equivalent. Some assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: The $\epsilon$-$\delta$ seems a red herring. For the converse, suppose the limit.of $f$ does not exist. What $g$ should you consider?

Comment: To go the other direction, if $\lim f(x)$ does not exist, consider $g(x)=-f(x)$.